# How to solve TS2322 error when doing this[prop] = data[prop]?

Tags: typescript

The code below doesn't work and I got stuck. How to I fix this?

```
type Data = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

class Person {
  id: number
  name: string

  constructor(personData: Data) {
    this.id = personData.id
    this.name = personData.name
  }

  update(updateData: Data) {
    for (const prop in updateData) {
      this[prop as keyof Data] = updateData[prop as keyof Data]
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUCWATALigDsBXAWwCMIAnAGixLnIiIGdgadiBzDAXwwYAxgBs4bNlAAKtNgHti6RviJkqtRsWasoHLryHZhi-aWHB5NABSQaC4vEREncAJTLs2YAAscbADp8FCg7B1cgvEZvP0DtFhCwxQj4iEZBRlIwPAQIayyc4AhXFwR3Ty8AMysoaxNiDlCaeTBcJQLc1w9MLy9ffwBtMGbWiSgAawgQeUrYMoBdEI6i1yGRqDHJ6dnXeeioQWxBfiA)

the Error:

> TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

The important line is in the update method: `this[prop as keyof Data] = updateData[prop as keyof Data]`. I suppose that typescript doesn't know that this[prop] and updateData[prop] are the same type (string|number). If all properties are the same type, there is no error. But how to tell typescript, that they are the of the same type?

Comment: This was a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it would be better to use composition here. That easily sidesteps the problem you're having.

```js
type Data = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

class Person {
  data: Data

  constructor(personData: Data) {
    this.data = personData
  }

  update(updateData: Data) {
    this.data = updateData
  }
}
```

If you really want to be able to access `id` and `name` as properties on a `Person` instance, you could add `get` accessors for them:

```js
get id() { return this.data.id }

get name() { return this.data.name }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5YAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoAafcuKiMgZzClAHNcBfXLgQAbOO3bIACtHYB7EDiZEMcMukxCCCBZygUEYOVAAUAB1kKNatKoCUSggTAALYOwB0KzMgC8yCyh5EGsmQSYKM28IE0jo63V7RydXdy9VP2Q4jAhQgnCCHggwQiITB2xkKGKKKEVUz284D2JkAuQikpAWGIqqmrrkBvTMD27WNoEhHRBOZHlWGSCFTJAIAHdpSxATbGIyAEZ6ZlYyACIAKTg1s-47AG5p3RKmgCZMvdJkAFZj8bZkJc5C4QLdHrgFhAlsEPNlICY3nYnrM5CIIB4RHIeCZIdCFC0iMdcdsxj0HrggA)

Comment: Excellent, I like composition for this (ideally without accessors, because of the duplication). Both typesafe *and* maintainable: adding a new property to `Data` doesn't require changes to `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't see a better option than asserting that `this` can be indexed by string, like this:

```typescript
(this as {[key: string]: any})[prop] = updateData[prop as keyof Data]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKUCWATALigDsBXAWwCMIAnAGixLnIiIGdgadiBzDAXwwYAxgBs4bNlAAKtNgHti6RviJkqtRsWasoHLryHZhi-aWHB5NABSQaC4vEREncAJTLs2YAAscbADp8FCg7B1cgvEZvP0DtFhCwxQj4iEZBRlIwPAQIayyc4AhXFwR3Ty8AMysoaxNiDlCaeTBcJQLc1w9MLy9rX38oCXQAbQBrCBB2Tm4eAF0iOGIQfjcRsGawOZCOotd1zaGpCZB5StgyueioQWxBfiA)

The `for-in` loop just makes this too dynamic to be statically checked.

---

Just a word of warning: Declaring that `updateData` is of type `Data` only ensures that it has the properties `id: number` and `name: string`. It **doesn't** ensure that `updateData` doesn't have **other** properties that you don't want to copy to your `Person` instance. For instance, this is a perfectly valid call to your `update` method:

```typescript
const somePerson = new Person({id: 1, name: "Shmoe"});
const data = {id: 2, name: "Joe", update: true};
somePerson.update(data);
```

...which will, of course, rather mess up that instance of `Person`. :-)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5YAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoAafcuKiMgZzClAHNcBfXLgQAbOO3bIACtHYB7EISoAHERFbhJ6TDibEylWtADcTECzbJO3ED1NMEC6xQRg5UABTLZC7XDJ+AJS6BARgABbA7AB0xMgAvMjeUPIgfrFETGGRMeasCUk+aRhw0XkQTIJMFMpEGBAeNXWQfgElwXihyDDuyB6OIJxJUHLKhIpN9UEhXX0RUcjiOADaANYQAJ4cXLwAumRwIBv8gcvKI8q7BZMtJWcXi5LrG3IwaCW7pl2CBIJVA0N5KwZCkFAUQBAAO7SIoebD6ZAARnozFYZAARABlcJUOQQdEnUwAsDIZpYRLw0jIABMKPKGIAUnj0SibpYuBQIPxTECICDUtE2R4yYEiU4SWTqQVKWQAMx0iwYgCyzO5uF5-IUgtq9WFJWpouQAHojcgACrhEaQyTQEZQXBAA)

Comment: do you have any advice for using a stricter type?

Comment: On first blush, I like [@JLRishe's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727016/157247).